# Laptop shutsdown when I, myself, go to sleep. Turns back on asking me to start in safe mode etc

Tags: windows-7, laptop, crash, sleep, nvidia-graphics-card

The laptop is connected to the wall plug, with the battery removed. I just leave the laptop on, go to sleep, and when I wake up, sometimes I'll find it already shut down (as opposed to the screen being turned off)

Sometimes 'whocrashed' will notice it, sometimes it will not.

A report from such a crash (not long after I had gone to sleep -- I must have left my computer sometime after 6 am):

> On Fri 14-Aug-15 06:41:06 GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\081415-23571-01.dmp This was probably caused by
>   the following module: nvlddmkm.sys (nvlddmkm+0x36E0B3)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x1000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF88004C570B3,
>   0xFFFFF880033BDC98, 0xFFFFF880033BD4F0) Error:
>   SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\nvlddmkm.sys product: NVIDIA Windows
>   Kernel Mode Driver, Version 355.60  company: NVIDIA Corporation
>   description: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 355.60  Bug
>   check description: This indicates that a system thread generated an
>   exception which the error handler did not catch. This appears to be a
>   typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a
>   hardware problem.  A third party driver was identified as the probable
>   root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an
>   update for the following driver: nvlddmkm.sys (NVIDIA Windows Kernel
>   Mode Driver, Version 355.60 , NVIDIA Corporation).  Google query:
>   NVIDIA Corporation SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M

Previously it was version `347.somethingsomething`.

I do not think the issue is easily reproducible, so I doubt the service will even take it seriously. I feel they'll just unnecessarily reformat my system and hand it back to me.

Comment: Do you have an OpenGL screen saver turned on?

Comment: I don't know what that is, so it can't be something I did knowingly. But I have no screensaver, after 10 minutes the screen is darkened (not sleep mode though)

Comment: When the computer is not used for some configured time, a screen saver can activate automatically. Some of them show 3D graphics. Something like this: https://youtu.be/IXEhK0c9k8I

Comment: Nope. Btw 'NVIDIA Corporation SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M' or 'nvidia nvlddmkm.sys' has a bunch of results but there is no actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you are in need of some better ventilation, a re-pasting/re-stickering of your heat sink in your laptop, or possibly a new processor fan. Run a stress test, and see if your laptop shuts down unexpectedly after an hour or two. If so, pursue the paste/sticker. At minimum, the fan could be dirty and in need of a dusting. But if it does not spin effortlessly, replace it.

Comment: laptop is new. right now it has been on for 20 hours and it is 58C

Comment: Please leave out the signature and email address for posts.  Just provide the answer material itself.